# How to use selenium to click a button with only type and class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to use selenium to click the button of "Submit" on Expedia. But none of the methods works.

I tired XPATHs, which doesn't work... And actually I am not sure which class I should feed into the XPATHs function.[html code of "submit" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJtmz.png)

Comment: first verify element is not present within iframe. if you can locate the element then tried to click on parent element. it works most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to click on button you can use below methods.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"your_path_to_chromedriver\chromedriver.exe") #path to connect with webdriver and chrome
driver.get("https://www.your_website.com")  
driver.find_element_by_id("enter_id").click() #add the id of button to click
driver.find_element_by_class_name("enter_class").click() #add the class of button to click
driver.find_element_by_xpath("enter_expath").click() #add the xpath to click on button
```

You can use id, class, or Xpath any of method to get the element and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the below code should work.

```
//button[@type='submit'][@class='btn-primary.btn-action.gcw-submit']
//button[type='submit'][class='btn-primary.btn-action.gcw-submit']
```